# accessing usb data lines in parallel

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I am attempting a project that is a basic usb keyboard logger.  I plan on using a PIC32 microcontroller that has built in USB host capabilities to interface to the keyboard.

My question is, can i hang off in parallel my MCU to read the data lines without affecting what is sent to the computer?  See the below picture.

[image]

Is this acceptable practice, or does the data need to be fed in series from the input->mcu->output connector?  Any issues with current draw?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this will not work. You will need either a µC with two USB ports (one host, one device mode) or two controllers.

USB works with exactly *one* host on a bus, and when you want multiple devices you have to use a hub. Note that a PC is always in host mode.

Comment: As I read the original post, the MCU will only monitor the USB traffic - it will be neither host nor device.  I suspect this would work, but I don't know enough about USB to make a definite statement.

Comment: I don't think that Pic32 supports USB monitor mode. OP clearly wants to use host mode.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like I will need to use an additional chip that can act as a device to forward the data on to the PC